# Too many subplots for pyplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am working on a program that plots a decent amount of graphs (the current iteration is outputting 250-300 graphs). I am using `subplots` so as to condense them to one output/window. However, the output is extremely condensed.

I was hoping that the output would maintain the dimensions of a "regular" plot and output a scroll-able window, as opposed to maintaining the dimensions of the output window and scaling the subplots down. Is there a way to fix this, besides outputting every *n* plots?

Here is the code that outputs the plots:

```
f, axarr = plt.subplots(len(events)-1, sharex = True)
x_axis = np.arange(120)
for i in range(len(events)-1):
    axarr[i].plot(x_axis,events[i])
plt.show()
```

Comment: In this situation I usually output pngs and use an image viewer to browse through the plots.

Comment: @cel Can you either expand on this in an answer or provide more info about how to do that, please?

Comment: To implement cel's suggestion, change your initial instance to `fig, ax = subplots(1,1)`. Inside the for loop, in addition to placing your plot on `ax`, you would also `fig.save(str(i)+'.png')`

Comment: Did you try to set the figure size? It works the following way: `f.set_size_inches((16, 12))`.

Comment: @jkalden I did try that: `f.set_size_inches((1000,12))`. Didn't seem to help at all, but perhaps I didn't input it properly.

Comment: @d0rmLife I use this statement before saving a plot to file. I guess `plt.show` will be unaffected... Try whether it helps you out when saving the plot. Could be at least a workaround...